# Android app installation not including SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, installation

I'm having a SQLite problem.  I've been developing with my attached devices, not the emulator.  This has always been fine.  I have built and installed the app many, many times on my phone and tablet.  A week or so ago, I made a change to the SQLite database that I have in my assets folder.  I uninstalled the app from my devices because I wanted a clean install, but now it seems like the database is never getting there.  it's the same code that's always been there.  This kind of thing:

PLEASE SEE THE BOTTOM FOR NEW CODE SAMPLE

```
private static String _DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.android.myapp/databases/";
private static final String _DATABASE_NAME = "myapp.sqlite";

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = _DB_PATH + _DATABASE_NAME;


        ***//THE PROBLEM IS THIS LINE, FOR WHATEVER REASON IT'S NO LONGER FINDING THE DATABASE IN THE ASSETS FOLDER
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);***


    } 
    catch (SQLiteException e) {
        //database does't exist yet.
    }
    if (checkDB != null) checkDB.close();

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (dbExist) {
        //do nothing - database already exist
    } 
    else {
        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
        //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        try {
            getReadableDatabase();
            copyDataBase();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}
```

It installs without error, but when I do something to access the DB on the device, it bombs on getReadableDatabase();.

Here's the LogCat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.myapp/com.android.myapp.ActivityL}:                 
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1748)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-09 21:55:26.250: E/AndroidRuntime(11474): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:149)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
at com.yesjapan.android.database.DatabaseHelper.createDataBase(DatabaseHelper.java:82)
at com.yesjapan.android.database.DbAdapter.open(DbAdapter.java:71)
at com.android.myapp.FragmentP.LoadC(FragmentP.java:226)
at com.android.myapp.FragmentP.onCreateView(FragmentP.java:97)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:735)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:926)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:909)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:1584)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4377)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1721)
```

I can install a previous version and it seems to work.  I've deleted and rebuilt from scratch the DB.  I have no idea why it doesn't think a database there or why the database is not installing.

This is so f'n frustrating to be spending time on this crap when there's code to be written!! arrgh!

EDIT:
here is another common error

```
11-10 17:33:55.983: E/Database(22087): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.android.myapp/databases/myapp.sqlite", &handle, 2, NULL) failed
```

EDIT: NEW CODE SAMPLE

```
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    //SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    File dbfile = null;
    try {
        //String myPath = _DB_PATH + _DATABASE_NAME;
        //File myPath = _helperContext.getDatabasePath(_DATABASE_NAME);
        //checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath.toString(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

        String myPath = _DB_PATH + _DATABASE_NAME;
        dbfile = new File(myPath);
        //checkdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.e("DatabaseHelper", e.getMessage());
    }
    //if (checkDB != null) checkDB.close();

    return dbfile.exists();         
    //return checkDB != null;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (dbExist) {
        //do nothing - database already exist
    } 
    else {
        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
        //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how large is the database file?

Comment: Please show the code `getReadableDatabase()`.  And, it is better to change `return checkDB != null ? true : false;` to `return checkDB != null;` even it will not solve the problem.

Comment: @wannik It's built-in

SQLiteDatabase android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase()

public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase () 
Since: API Level 1

Comment: @AlanMoore It's 108k in size.

Comment: Your class `DatabaseHelper` extends from?

Comment: @wannik public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper.

I should reiterate that this all worked...same code...a week ago.  I added some records to the database, uninstalled the apps from phone and tablet and reinstalled.

Comment: I was wondering why you have to manage the creation of the database manually. Using `SQLiteOpenHelper` will check whether the database is exist (if not it will create it for you.) Moreover, I would call `getReadableDatabase()` from outside this class.

Comment: @wannik This is the method I've most often seen online.  I am including my own database in the assets folder and it doesn't appear to be getting installed.

Answer (score 0):

Run `unzip -l <your_app.apk>` and make sure that the db is getting included.  If it's not there, try doing a clean build.

Comment: Congratz on the L33t reputation :P

Comment: @levis501 Yes, the database is there.  What do you mean by "clean build"?

Comment: @levi501 If you mean "clean" in the Project menu, I've done that countless times :).

Comment: Ok, if it's in the APK, then never mind about the clean build.  The database is getting to your device and the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: If you haven't already, make sure you aren't out of space on your device.

Comment: Also, can you tell us the version of Android on the device that is having a problem?  getWritableDatabase() shouldn't be throwing a NullPointerException under normal circumstances, and I'd like to see what the source code is doing at the line mentioned in the stack trace.

Comment: One more thing that might help get to the bottom of this.  Have checkDataBase() log the exact SQLiteException exception that is occurring.  It might give more info as to the cause of the failure.

Comment: @levis501 Sorry for the delay ...<sheepishly>Skyrim :)</sheepishly>... I changed the code sample at the bottom of the original post.  trying some of the other suggestions.  My phone is running 2.2 and tablet is 3.1.  How can I get the exact SQLException error for you?  Thanks again for helping!

Comment: @levis501 no kidding, later the night i made that last comment, my phone upgraded to 2.3.4 and my tablet upgraded to 3.2.  For some reason unknown to me, the phone now appears to be working.  Still have the problem on the tablet though.  Thanks.

Comment: @levis501 Does the database get installed in the same place by default on a tablet as on a phone?

Answer (score 0):

First of all never hard code the path, as different OEM can change the anytime making your app unusable instead use [getDatabasePath()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: All the examples I remember have it hardcoded like I have...and I haven't liked it much.  I will make that change, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please relapse below line. in your code

```
checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

Instead of

```
checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

Thanks